# What is the best PHP developer setup for Windows 7 64bit?

Tags: php, iis

What is the best PHP developer setup for Windows 7 64bit? I just purchased PhpStorm and what to get a developer env setup on my Win 7 laptop.

Comment: Please leave comment as to why you would vote to close. I feel like a community is a great place to learn where to get started before writing allot of code on the wrong path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps I'm oldschool, but the easiest I've found yet is http://www.wampserver.com

My personal editor of choice is notepad++ for quick stuff, and Netbeans for more involved code.

While I was a longtime phpMyAdmin (or command line) person, having played with [Navicat](http://www.navicat.com/), I'm officially hooked.  Though I do have to give props for [MySql Workbench](http://wb.mysql.com/) too.  You just can't beat free.

Answer (score 2):

I've used http://zwamp.sourceforge.net/ before. It's pretty simple to set up. Includes apache, php, mysql, perl, etc.

Answer (score 1):

My current setup is to run eclipse php helios on my pc running win7 and have another pc (or you can have a virtual machine) running ubuntu server 10.04 running all my php/mysql/apache/solr stuff.

For mysql editing I use phpmyadmin (running on the ubuntu machine) and heidi sql (running on my local machine)

Answer (score 0):

HeidiSQL is a great an open source/ free tool for MySQL, you may want to check it.